# Incrementally compiling rules in Drools 6

Tags: java, drools, kie

I am working on a drools based rule engine. I have initially around 10000 rules, which I have loaded on KieBase using KieFileSystem. Now I want to add another rule to this KieBase, without having to recompile earlier 10000 rules again. Does the new Kie APIs provide in drool 6 allow this to happen?(A working example would be helpful)

PS: While using `KieBase.newKieSession()` or `KieSession.getClassPathContainer()` are the rules in KieFileSystem getting recompiled?